# jQuery audio loop with excess pause (Buzz plugin)

Tags: loops, audio, repeat, buzz.js

I use Buzz plugin for plaing audio on my page. I used loop function and add some samples for it [Buzz audio plugin](http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/). Every thing works fine: loop work and sample sounds, but I have a little pause beetwen repeating each sounds (samples was cuted without any peaces of silents).

How can I controll loop speed of "buzz" plugin, and delete pause beetwen repeating? Beetwen all samples have differents duration

```
this.loop = function() {
            if (!supported) {
                return this;
            }
            this.sound.loop = "loop";
            this.bind("ended.buzzloop", function() {
                this.currentTime = 0;
                this.play();
            });
            return this;
        };
```

It's buzz plugin loop function

Comment: Also having this issue.  I don't see anything in the docs about controlling the loop; just loop() and unloop().

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem isn't with Buzz.js, but with [mp3 audio](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/25846/is-it-possible-to-loop-mp3-without-gaps).  Try using a different format (such as Ogg Vorbis).

**UPDATE**
So, even after I switched to ogg vorbis, [I'm still getting the gap between loops](http://jsfiddle.net/stupid_genius/yfd8yjgz/12/).  It's starting to seem like an issue with Buzz.js.

```
SC.get('/resolve', { url: mySound.track_url }, function(res, err) {
  mySound.track = new buzz.sound(res.stream_url+'?client_id='+mySound.client_id);
  mySound.track.bindOnce('canplay', function(e){
    mySound.track.loop().play();
    console.log('ready');
  });
});
```

I think I'll end up trying the alternating-between-two-tracks approach.